# How does a Switch Fabric Module work internally?

Tags: switch, switching, network-core, network

I am interested how does a switch fabric module work internally.

What interfaces does it use to physically connect the I/O modules on switches? Where are the CAM / MAC tables of the switch? Are there two different instances of those MAC tables? What kind of wiring is it used to interconnect the I/O ports?

Do these switch fabric modules have a separate processor? Do they have some kind of ASIC?